# Powershell (Windows 10) has yellow cmd characters - inconsistent with modified properties

Tags: powershell, textcolor

On Windows 10 Home in the powershell opened from the alternate start menu (right click) the command line characters are yellow.  This is not the color I configured via the Properties dialog.

This occurs for the Administrator (privileged) shell as well as the User shell.  In neither case is yellow a configuration setting chosen through the Properties dialog for anything.

Comment: Which color do you see if you start powershell in `cmd,exe` with `start powershell` ? Take a look at your ps-profiles: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `Remove-Module PSReadline`

Comment: The properties are stored in the `Console` registry key in `HKCU` per console host shortcut. Launch the console host from a different place, get a different set of properties.

Comment: Aedvald Tseh - in a PS started from CMD all input and output is white on blue background.

Comment: PetSerAl - while your solution may be correct (I don't know) I'm not about to go removing objects without some contextual justification.  In looking into PSReadline I found that $profile  is %User...%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1  and  \Documents\WindowsPowerShell  dir does note exist.

Comment: BenH - Your observation - different launch shortcut different properties - makes perfect sense; however, I've modified that launch point with the MS provided tool and ended up with something nonsensical.  Where can I find the shortcut in the registry to see what has been set to yellow?

Comment: Sorry folks I'm a NOOB on this site and couldn't figure out promptly how to interleave my responses.